# How to represent a schedule for Timetabler Problem in Genetic Algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

For genetic algorithms usually genes symbolized like this:

```
PARENT1: 101101010101001001001001110011100110101011101101
PARENT2: 010100111011010101110101001001101011001010010110
```

so crossover, mutations may be done with this representations as like:

Choose a crossover point:

```
PARENT1: 1011010101010010 01001001110011100110101011101101
PARENT2: 0101001110110101 01110101001001101011001010010110
```

Perform crossover to produce a child:

```
CHILD: 1011010101010010 01110101001001101011001010010110
```

Which then becomes, a whole new chromosome:

```
CHILD: 101101010101001001110101001001101011001010010110
```

My problem is how to represent a weekly schedule gene in Java?

Examples are taken from this article: http://secretgeek.net/content/bambrilg.pdf

I am impelementing this timetabling problem in Java and want to represent

```
FIGURE 10: An Entire University Timetable
```

in Java.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you have availability to use Matlab and you have

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you have availability to use Matlab and you have no constraint to use Java. I suggest to go for Matlab. In my personal experience, Matlab has awesome GA and Soft Computing toolbox. worth exploring.

Comment: @Nishant I have to impelement in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below might give you an idea how to approach the problem. One solution (which would be the university timetable) consists out of an array of single rooms. These single rooms each have a 2dimensional array, where the columns are the days, and the rows are the hours. I set the HOURS to 16, since I think in the night time there will be no classes. So Hour Row 1 would be the first hour of the day... probably from 7 to 8 AM. The values of the array show which class is booked.

```
public class SingleRoom {
    static final int DAYS  = 7;
    static final int HOURS = 16;
    . . .
    private int[][] timetable = new int[DAYS][HOURS];   //0 would say room is not booked, >0 indicates the booked class (english advanced (12), object oriented programming (139), etc..)
}

public class Solution {
    static final int AVAILABLE_ROOMS = 26;
    . . .
    private SingleRoom[] university_timetable = new SingleRoom[AVAILABLE_ROOMS];    
}
```

mutations:

change class mutation - change the class to another random class or to zero = no booking

switch on / off class - if an hour at a day in a specific room is booked, switch it off
                        if it is not booked, switch it on with a random class
                this is to give the algorithm the possibility to not book hours, since in the change class mutation the 0 has a low probability to be chosen

constraints:
   after creating your solutions, check against all constraints and keep the solutions that are valid
   the new valid solutions have to be inserted into your population (of solutions), if they are better to other solutions already in your population or if they enhance the diversity of your population

But in the document you referred to it is fairly good described how to implement a GA for this problem (starts with page 16).

I wrote a generic java framework for the multi-objective optimisation algorithm mPOEMS (Multiobjective prototype optimization with evolved improvement steps), which is a GA using evolutionary concepts.

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/mr-stateradio/mpoems-in-java), it might give you an idea how to approach your problem:

The solutions which you can find with this algorithm have been compared in a scientific work with state-of-the-art algorithms SPEA-2 and NSGA, and it has been proven that 
the algorithm performes comparable or even better, depending on the metrics you take to measure the performance.

You can find it [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6W86-506J0FF-1&_user=10&_coverDate=01/31/2011&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1592523780&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=b186457829f2884fb8a724ae25df4398&searchtype=a).

Further resources:
My thesis which applies this framework to the project selection problem:
http://www.ub.tuwien.ac.at/dipl/2008/AC05038968.pdf

The documentation of the framework:
http://thomaskremmel.com/mpoems/mpoems_in_java_documentation.pdf

mPOEMS presentation paper:
http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1792634.1792653

Actually with a bit of enthusiasm you could easily adapt the code of the generic framework to your needs.

Do you write this GA in your job or as a student?

Comment: I couldn't have a time to reply this comment. I will try to find a solution according to your advices. I am implementing it for school not for job.

Comment: You suggested a two dimensional array for timetable(row, column). Is it logical to change it into an array. I mean, for example defining different indexes to Monday 7 to 8 AM, Monday 8 to 9 AM,...., Tuesday 7 to 8 AM, Tuesday 8 to 9 AM,.... so on?

Comment: Your mutation offers are quiet well but how about crossovers?

Comment: There are different crossover approaches available: http://www.optiwater.com/optiga/crossover.html        I used this algorithm: create two childs, fill the first child with a 50/50 probability selecting genes from first / second parent, create second child with the genes not selected for the first child. You can find my code here: http://pastebin.com/9Z2PERw9 ,whereas it might be a bit confusing since mPOEMS is using an action concept, above the actual solution layer. But it gives you an idea how to do a crossover.

Comment: your one dimensional array approach sounds reasonable, and might be easier to deal with. Nevertheless I would go for the two dimensional ;-)

Comment: @Tom Tom, thanks for your help. I implemented that algorithm and it works well. I will run it with real values and test its performance. I will need to optimize the parameters of population size, number of genes to kill and weight of constraints so I want to discuss that optimization with you too. Accepting as an answer, thanks again.

Comment: One more, I used two dimensional model too.

Comment: @Tom Tom, we have a tree dimensional gene for our genetic algorithm here. These are: days, hours and classrooms. How would you design it if you had to add another dimension: instructors. I have to add it because I should implement genetic algorithms to schedule final exams and assign instructors as observers for each exam. So I will have: days, hours, classrooms and instructors as dimensions. How can be represented it at Java?